# Sentry One Plan Explorer History Tab

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

While I'm working on index tuning I would love the history bar to populate with each run so I can see the differences, I'm probably using the tool incorrectly. My current workflow is:

```
Create New Plan Explorer Session
Paste Query
Click "Get Actual Plan"
go to Index Analysis
either use the <S> or manually script out an index change
click "Get Actual Plan" again and instead of adding history version 2 it just overwrites history version 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Plan Explorer user preferences (Tools -> User Preferences), uncheck the box reading "Only save history if command text or connection settings change".

If this does not work, try adding something to the query itself that is inconsequential - a line break, an extra space between tokens, something of that nature. This will both trigger a change to the command text *and* cause a new query plan hash to be generated by SQL Server.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!!!